# .NET Core MSTests fail because of "Illegal characters in path"

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, mstest

When I click Run All .NET Core tests (the MSTest version) they do not run.  It fails saying in the bottom left corner "Unexpected error detected.  Check the Tests Output Pane for details".

I checked the output and this is the error:

> [4/8/2018 19:29:53 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
>   [4/8/2018 19:29:53 Error] System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.

I created a blank project called "Thing.Tests".  The path is

> C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\Thing.Tests\Thing.Tests\Thing.Tests.csproj

What the issue is??

Comment: It’s possible the path is too long.  Try to create the project somewhere like c:/code/

Comment: That didn't make a difference :(

Comment: What about without space in the path? Shot in the dark...

Comment: That also did not make a difference:
"C:\test\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1.csproj"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out your system PATH:

```
echo %PATH%
```

I ended up having an entry with double quotes (which Visual Studio didn't like very much). Once I deleted that entry it worked like a charm.

You can edit it through the Environment Variables

```
Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables
```

Comment: Another note, after you do this, I needed to close and reopen my command prompt and my Visual Studio.  I had both " and ' as bad characters, removed both, re-opened and was good.  Really stupid bug in VS though! lol

Comment: I deleted from my PATH the double quotes that surrounded. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin"; to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin.

Comment: In my case I did not have the C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin in my PATH variable... I added it and it fixed my issue

Comment: In my case, a random app decided that it should put a path in with double quotes. 
Note that the quotes don't show up when editing the paths, so you have to change the single path entry, save, then change it back to without quotes. 
WHY does this brick VS? 

Comment: You will have to restart your machine to have the PATH var change. Test with the command suggested above to see if it's been applied.